# Desire + Gerund (-ing verb)?

Tags: grammar

Which of these statements is more grammatically correct:

*"I believe that this will contribute to my long-standing desire of bridging the gap that exists between them."*

or

*"I believe that this will contribute to my long-standing desire to bridge the gap that exists between them."*

Thank you!

Comment: Hello ConfusedAtMIdnight! I'm voting to move this question over to English.SE, that is more appropriate for this kind of topics.

Answer (score 0):

Ngrams show that *desire of bridging* was widely used in the 19th century. However, it has almost completely vanished, so *desire to bridge* seems to be your only choice of you want to write something that sounds like 21st century English.

However, I wouldn't say that 19th-century English is ungrammatical.

See Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=desire+of+making%2Cdesire+for+making%2Cdesire+to+make&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdesire%20of%20making%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdesire%20for%20making%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdesire%20to%20make%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Look what's happened to 'desirous of'!